# How to allow the hash character in the URL?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

My app only has two kinds of URLs: `/` (root URL) and `/id` (for example: `/something`). But now I need to allow two parameters separated by a hash character, like this: `/something/param1/#/param2`.

So in my `nuxt.config.js` I added:

```js
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      path: '/:id/:location/#/:action',
      components: {
        default: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/_id')
      },
      chunkNames: {
        modal: 'pages/_id'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But then `/something/param1/#/param2` URL gives a 404 page..

If instead I do:

```js
routes.push({
  path: '/:id/:location/hash/:action'
})
```

...and try the URL `/something/param1/hash/param2` then it works fine. But, I want to use `#` between my two other parameters in the URL, not `hash` or anything else.

Any idea if this is possible and how to achieve it?

Comment: Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url

Comment: @Radeanu thanks, looks like `Nuxt` is actually expecting `%23` instead of `#` though. I did `path: '/:id/:location/%23/:action',` and `/something/param1/#/param2` fails although `/something/param1/%23/param2` works. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867513/8816585
You can see the valid characters in an URL, mainly letters and some small subset of special chars. `/` do serve as a separation for files and directories.

I'm not sure if you saw `/#/` being used somewhere but it's clearly not standard, maybe not properly supported by all the browsers and probably not a good idea neither. Why the need to something like this?